# Master Chief John-117 real face?

Tags: halo

In the Short TV series, Halo: Forward Unto Dawn, the end of last episode shows faces of two cybernetically enhanced soldiers but Master Chief John-117 is shown with his helmet. In the Halo Universe what is the real facial appearance of Master Chief John-117?
Is he shown without his helmet in any of the games?

Comment: They have, so far, strayed from showing his face because they wanted to "allow every player to imagine themselves as the Master Chief - to feel like they are a part of the game"

Comment: Does he remove his helmet in the new series where he's played by Pablo Schreiber?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only official image of Master Chief (John-117) was a post credits scene once the player completes Halo 4 on the Legendary difficulty setting.  The scene is Master Chief having his Mjolnir armor removed, with the helmet being last.  The image shown is merely his eyes.

[image]

However franchise development director Frank O'Connor gave a description of Master Chief's appearance in an interview with GameTrailers: “an older man, almost painfully pale, almost albino white, with pale blue eyes, reddish hair, close cropped to a skin head, and maybe the last remnants of freckles he had when he was a kid.”

Comment: Is the image CG or actor?  If an actor do we know who it is?

Comment: @DavidStarkey I believe it's CG.  the actor Daniel Cudmore (most known for playing Colossus in the X-men franchise) portrayed him in Forward Unto Dawn

Comment: In the first book I believe there's a description of him but I can't find it. Halo Nation has a similar description to what I remember though, " As a child, John had brown hair, freckles, and a small gap between his front teeth"

Answer (score 6):

In the 2015 animated film Halo: Fall Of Reach, John's face is shown at 6 years old and shortly before putting his MJOLNIR helmet on for the first time. There are no live-action images of Spartan-117's face apart from the image in Monty129's answer above.
[image]
[image]
[image]